# Select row with highest column values

Tags: mysql

am having a database with above data and i want to select only country with highest registrars

here is my query

```
SELECT COUNTRY FROM USERS HAVING COUNTRY = MAX(COUNTRY)
```

TABLE USERS

```
ID NAME COUNTRY

1  JOHN  USA
2  JOHN  CA
3  JOHN  USA
4  JOHN  UK
5  JOHN  USA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

**EDIT:**
Just remove `COUNT(*) As Total`

```
SELECT COUNTRY
FROM USERS 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this works, but am only getting id count like it outputs 3 IDS, but i want to get name like USA instead counting ids

Comment: Just the country name?